# NSPredicate: looking for a simpler code

Tags: objective-c

I am not familiar with NSPredicate syntax. The following line of code does what I want. But I wonder if there is a more concise way to do it.

Plus, any cheat sheet on NSPredicate syntax is much appreciated. The Apple doc on NSPredicate seems to me far more complex for practical purpose.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR SELF.city CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR SELF.state CONTAINS[cd] %@",aString, aString, aString];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fine. I doubt there are many ways you can "improve" or simplify your predicate for such a simple purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSPredicate's subclass [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCompoundPredicate/orPredicateWithSubpredicates)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                               @[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", aString], 
                                 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.city CONTAINS[cd] %@", aString], 
                                 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.state CONTAINS[cd] %@", aString]
                                ]
                         ];
```

But

> «Two of more — use a for» <sub>Edsger W. Dijkstra</sub>
>   «Or an enumeration» <sub>vikingosegundo</sub>

```
NSString *aString =@"Ney York";
NSMutableArray *predicates = [@[] mutableCopy];
[@[@"name", @"city", @"state"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %%@", obj];
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format, aString]];
}];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```